# Coroutine in launch or withcontent not cancel when call scope.cancel()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have called scope.cancel() but coroutine in launch2 and withcontext not cancel. It still show log with "complete text"

```
runBlocking {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            this.cancel()
            println("launch1 complete")
        }
        launch {
            println("launch2 running")
            delay(2000)
            println("launch2 complete")
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("withContext running")
            delay(2000)
            println("withContext complete")
        }
    }
```

LOG :

1. withContext running
2. launch2 running
3. launch1 complete
4. withContext complete
5. launch2 complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only cancel the scope of the first launch because you create the runBlocking Scope and inside this scope three new scopes. 
If you call `this` in the launch scope, it means the launch scope not the runBlocking scope. To cancel the runBlocking scope call

```
this@runBlocking.cancel()
```

Comment: I have an other question. Does kotlin create new scope for new coroutine ? as I know it should be run in scope of runblocking. It mean in all of my code, we have only one scope.

Comment: `runBlocking` creates its own CoroutineScope that lives for the length of time that `runBlocking` takes to complete. It is the receiver of the lambda, so you are launching those other coroutines in the CoroutineScope of the `runBlocking`. `launch` and `async` never create their own CoroutineScopes. However, `withContext` *does* create its own CoroutineScope that is internal to its lambda, so you could launch coroutines from that.